# Material action bar background using a custom xml

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Hi I need to make like an action bar for my custom view background and I tried using

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/button_gradient" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/list_pressed" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/menu_label" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

But I am not getting the shadow with this code. What should I change to get the shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBar is deprecated. Switch to a Toolbar, and you should get your shadow.